# Get application name from its package name via adb

Tags: android, shell, adb

I want to make a simple script that would allow me to uninstall default android apps with ADB.

It should list packages and allow the user to select which one they want to remove in a format like this.

Youtube (com.google.android.youtube)

Chrome (com.google.android.chrome)

...

I can get packages with "pm list packages" command.
How can I get an application's name from its package name?

Comment: You can pass package name to `adb uninstall`, for example `adb uninstall com.farproc.wifi.analyzer`

Comment: You didn't get my point. I want to get the application's name from its package name.